# How to Inserting data with php-curl

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to print the links of the images in the database.
https://www.yelp.com/biz_photos/zesty-gyros-and-deli-grand-rapids

**I connected using CURL. I took the links to the pictures using Preg_match_all and listed them as "FOR". But I get the error in the INSERT process to the database.**

Parse the data

```
preg_match_all('@<div class="photo-box photo-box--interactive" data-photo-id=(.*?)>@si', $site, $mydata); 

for ($a=0; $a<count($mydata[1]); $a++) {
    echo $mydata[1][$a].'<br>';
}
```

25 results are listed below. But I couldn't do mysql insert.

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO myTable (field) VALUES ($mydata[1][$a])") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Try to debug the exact query tries to run. Also provide the error if you have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use single quotations marks around your $mydata[1][$a] and put in mysqli_real_escape_string function.

```
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $mydata[1][$a]);
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO myTable (field) VALUES ('".$value."')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: He gave me this error. 25 separate results.  He gave me this error. 25 separate results....Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: then check your variable `$link` if it's `null` or a mysql resource

Comment: you need to pass "$conn" inside your function!

Comment: use "global $conn" inside your function just like this:
    function siteConnect($site) {
      global $conn;

Comment: I used it. function siteConnect($site) { global $conn; $ch = curl_init();           Notice: Undefined variable: value in..... 30    It's failed on line 30. Line 30 is   Error:    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO yelp_image_list (business_id, businesname, yelp, yelp_image_id) 
  VALUES ('1', '12', '123', '".$value."')") 
  or die(mysqli_error($conn));

Comment: I've solved the problem by placing the mysqli INSERT section and the "Value" variable under the "FOR" loop. Thank you all.                                                                                         
  preg_match_all('@<div class="photo-box photo-box--interactive" data-photo-id=(.*?)>@si',$site,$mydata);
  for ($a=0; $a<count($mydata[1]); $a++){
  $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $mydata[1][$a]);
  mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO yelp_image_list (business_id, businesname, yelp, yelp_image_id) 
  VALUES ('1', '12', '123', '".$value."')")